# jQuery autocomplete multiple values from selectbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using the following code to setup autocomplete to my web application. Everything works fine in jsfiddle and here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/JhRL5/1/

```
 <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Types of Bear" data-role="none" multiple class="chosen-select-width" tabindex="16" id="test">
        <option value="" disable></option>
        <option value="3">American Black Bear</option>
        <option value="4">Asiatic Black Bear</option>
        <option value="5">Brown Bear</option>
        <option value="6">Giant Panda</option>
        <option value="7">Sloth Bear</option>
        <option value="8">Sun Bear</option>
        <option value="9">Polar Bear</option>
        <option value="10">Spectacled Bear</option>
      </select>
```

Javascript

```
 var config = {
      '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"75%"}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#test").change(function(){
        var a = $("#test :selected").text();
        $("#selectedlist").html(a);
    });

    $("#s-all").click(function(){

        var a = $("#test option");

        $.each( a, function( i, val ) {
            $(val).change();
        });

        var b = $("#test option").text();
        $("#selectedlist").html(b);

    });

    $("#c-all").click(function(){

        $("#test option:selected").removeAttr("selected");

        var a = $("#test :selected").text();
        $("#selectedlist").html(a);
        $(".chosen-choices").find("li.search-choice").remove();

    });

});
```

CSS

```
#selectedlist { border: solid 1px #eee; margin-top:20px; padding:10px}
#selectedlist span{width: 100%; float: left;}
```

Please refer to the jsfiddle link and everything seems working fine in the jsfiddle but the same code not working in my website.

Please check my website link at http://20percents.tk/backend/extra-pages/test1/

I tried setting up the CSS property as `select.not('test1')` also but still it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It might be due to the error that occurs as soon as you load the page on your real site, "TypeError: a is null" in {main,places}.js. Sometimes an error in a separate script can cause other JS to stop working.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Fixed it once I moved the script little up.

Answer (score 0):

It started working after placing the script in different position. Must be jquery conflict.